# Objective-C get the number of twitter followers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to get the number of twitter followers in my iOS App.

I find some Documentation regarding this issue:
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup

This is the code I have so far:

```
    NSString *apiURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=%@", @"barackobama"];

    NSURL *apiURL = [NSURL URLWithString:apiURLString];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:apiURL];

    request.HTTPMethod = @"GET"; 

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

//        ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode

        NSLog(@"response = %@", response);
    }];
```

However, I am pretty confused as how to send all the other parameters required for the request.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: look into using [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) it will greatly simplify sending HTTP requests

Comment: Or better yet, use STTwitter